# Как скомпилировать и запустить библиотеку SFML/Network.hpp в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, сеть, sfml

использую Visual Studio Code, операционная система Debian 12. Программа из учебника - простейший сканер порта. Идёт обращение на локальном хосте к порту 80, если порт открыт то возвращается строка **OPEN**, иначе **CLOSED**. Код файла **scaner5_2.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool is_port_open(const std::string& address, int port)
{
    return (sf::TcpSocket().connect(address,port) == sf::Socket::Done);
}

int main()
{
    if (is_port_open("localhost",80))
    {
        cout << "OPEN";
    }else{
        cout << "CLOSED";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Код файла **Makefile**:

```
CXX       := g++
CXX_FLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb

BIN     := bin
SRC     := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB     := lib

LIBRARIES   := 
EXECUTABLE  := scaner5_2


all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

run: clean all
    clear
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -L$(LIB) $^ -o $@ $(LIBRARIES)

clean:
    -rm $(BIN)/*
```

Ссылка на zip архив с проектом на githab *https://github.com/goodwin039/C-/blob/main/Scaner_5_2.zip*. Ссылка на архив, а не на сам код потому, что пока не разобрался как гитом на линуксе пользоваться.

В общем на Visual studio Code, используя расширение **Easy C++ projects  v2.0.0** создал проект, далее в терминале воспользовался командой **make**, но вышли ошибки:

```
user@debian:~/projects/Scaner_5_2$ make
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -ggdb -Iinclude -Llib src/scaner5_2.cpp -o bin/scaner5_2 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccegUOta.o: предупреждение: перемещение указывает на «_ZN2sf4Time4ZeroE» из раздела только для чтения «.text»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccegUOta.o: в функции «is_port_open(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)»:
/home/user/projects/Scaner_5_2/src/scaner5_2.cpp:9: неопределённая ссылка на «sf::TcpSocket::TcpSocket()»
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/projects/Scaner_5_2/src/scaner5_2.cpp:9: неопределённая ссылка на «sf::IpAddress::IpAddress(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)»
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/projects/Scaner_5_2/src/scaner5_2.cpp:9: неопределённая ссылка на «sf::Time::Zero»
/usr/bin/ld: /home/user/projects/Scaner_5_2/src/scaner5_2.cpp:9: неопределённая ссылка на «sf::TcpSocket::connect(sf::IpAddress const&, unsigned short, sf::Time)»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccegUOta.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN2sf9TcpSocketE[_ZTIN2sf9TcpSocketE]+0x10): неопределённая ссылка на «typeinfo for sf::Socket»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccegUOta.o: в функции «sf::TcpSocket::~TcpSocket()»:
/usr/include/SFML/Network/TcpSocket.hpp:46: неопределённая ссылка на «sf::Socket::~Socket()»
/usr/bin/ld: предупреждение: создаётся DT_TEXTREL в PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:20: bin/scaner5_2] Ошибка 1
```

Так понимаю в файле **Makefile**, в строке *LIBRARIES   :=* требуется указать список библиотек. Подскажите какие библиотеки требуется подключить чтобы исправить ошибку.

P.S. SFML  командой *sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev* уже установил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо того, чтобы спрашивать у нас конкретный флаг (вы же не собираетесь про каждую новую библиотеку тут спрашивать), лучше понять принцип.

Нормальные библиотеки сообщают необходимые флаги через `pkg-config`.

Сначала определяем имя библиотеки в pkg-config: `pkg-config --list-all | grep -i sfml`.

Если вдруг такой поиск ничего не находит (для SFML находит), открываем [список файлов в пакете](https://packages.debian.org/sid/alpha/libsfml-dev/filelist) и ищем там `.pc`. Имя файла без пути и без расширения `.pc` = имя для pkg-config.

Потом зовем `pkg-config --libs ИмяБиблиотеки` используя это имя, чтобы узнать флаги линковщика. Бонусные очки, если будете делать это автоматически из мейкфайла.

Еще стоит позвать `pkg-config --cflags ИмяБиблиотеки` и вписать это во флаги компилятора (для каких-то библиотек и без этого работает, но лучше это делать всегда).

Если в списке файлов в пакете нет `.pc`, то вместо этого ищем там одно из: `lib??.a`, `lib??.so` (только линукс), `lib??.dll.a` (только винда), и используем флаг `-l??` (`-l` плюс имя файла без префикса `lib` и без расширения).

Comment: Кто минус обронил? Я не могу исправить ошибку в ответе, если я про нее не знаю

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, помогло. Минус поднял до 0, дальше пока сил не хватает. В общем вы правы, что не нужно про каждую библиотеку спрашивать, просто не знал откуда начинать. Только сегодня от Вас узнал о pkg-config. Установил данную утилиту и настроил по Вашей инструкции. Самый последний вопрос - скажите как делать это автоматически из мейкфайла?

Comment: @student007 Проще всего так: `LIBRARIES := $(shell pkg-config --libs ИмяБиблиотеки)`.